# RadioButton Error using Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, radio-button

I'm trying to get a basic GUI with some radiobuttons working using tkinter however I'm having some trouble creating radiobuttons.

```
import Tkinter as tk   # python
...
def createView(self):
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Choose mode analysis", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        form_analysis = tk.BooleanVar()

        # form_analysis_radioButton = tk.RadioButton(self, text="Form Analysis")
                                    # variable=form_analysis, value=True)
        # match_analysis_radioButton = tk.RadioButton(self, text="Match Analysis",
        #                                             variable=form_analysis,
        #                                             value=False)
        # form_analysis_radioButton.pack()
        # match_analysis_radioButton.pack()
```

which throws this error
  File "gui_test.py", line 72, in createView

```
    form_analysis_radioButton = tk.RadioButton(self, text="Form Analysis")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RadioButton'
```

This seems to be telling me that there is no RadioButton function in the tk module (not sure why it says 'module' instead of 'tkinter' though) so I checked in the command line and got this

```
In [2]: import Tkinter as tk

In [3]: tk.RadioButton()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-1404e954a1fa> in <module>()
----> 1 tk.RadioButton()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'RadioButton'

In [4]: from Tkinter import *

In [5]: RadioButton()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-0d02b97652df> in <module>()
----> 1 RadioButton()

NameError: name 'RadioButton' is not defined
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a simple typo: `RadioButton` should be replaced with [`Radiobutton`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/radiobutton.htm).

Comment: ah of course thank you. do you know why it said 'module' instead of 'tkinter' though?

Comment: @guribe94, You're welcome. Because the qualifer `Tkinter` (`tk`) is a module. Try `type(tk)`

Answer (score 0):

`RadioButton()` doesn't exist, rather it is `Radiobutton`. This is akward, because tkinter always capitalizes in between of compound words. Like, for a dropdown choice, you do `StringVar`. For compound words, it capitalizes in between.